# pdfplumber memory hogging with discord bot

Tags: python, discord, pdfplumber, discord-interactions

I was using a command to fetch a pdf and format it asynchronously. This is the command:

```
async def ext_command(self, ctx:interactions.CommandContext, page: int = None):
await ctx.defer(ephemeral=False)
loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        r = await response.content.read()
        chunk = await loop.run_in_executor(None, self.pdf_process, r, page)
        for i in range(0,len(chunk)):
            await ctx.send(chunk[i])
```

And this is for pdf processing:

```
def pdf_process(self, r, page):
with pdfplumber.open(BytesIO(r)) as pdf:
    if page != None:
        extracted_page = pdf.pages[page-1].extract_text()
    else:
        current_day = datetime.datetime.now().timetuple().tm_yday
        current_month = datetime.date.today().month
        page = current_day + current_month + 7
        year = datetime.date.today().year
        if (year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0) or year % 400 == 0:
            page -= 1
        req_page = pdf.pages[page-1]
        extracted_page = req_page.extract_text()
        del req_page._objects()
        del req_page._layout()
        req_page.flush_cache()
        req_page.get_text_layout.cache_clear()
        gc.collect()
chunklength = 1900
    
indexes = []
chunk = ''
label = 0
indexes = [i for i, letter in enumerate(extracted_page) if letter == '\n']
for i in range(0,len(indexes)):
    if extracted_page[indexes[i]-1] == ' ':
        if extracted_page[indexes[i]-2] == '.' or extracted_page[indexes[i]-2] == '"' or extracted_page[indexes[i]-2] == '!' or extracted_page[indexes[i]-2] == ' ' or extracted_page[indexes[i]-2] == '?':
            if label == 0:
                label = indexes[i]
                chunk = extracted_page[:indexes[i]] + '\n'
            else:
                chunk += extracted_page[label:indexes[i]] + '\n'
                label = indexes[i]
chunk += extracted_page[label:len(extracted_page)-1]
chunks = [chunk[i:i+chunklength] for i in range (0, len(chunk), chunklength)]
return chunks
```

I checked out the memory leak issue at the github page and made changes (added `req_page.flush_cache()` and `req_page.get_text_layout.cache_clear()` and it shows no change whatsoever. I used memory_profiler at pdf_process() and this is what it shows:
[image]
As it shows at line 27 and 28, the taken up memory is never released and with each subsequent run of this particular command, the memory keeps on growing.

tldr; using pdfplumber in a discord bot, memory consumption going up with each command run, tried using [fix](https://github.com/jsvine/pdfplumber/issues/193#issuecomment-776726846) at its github, no luck.

Please help

Comment: You didn't show the number after `gc.collect()`.  That's where the deleted items would get reclaimed, and the `BytesIO` copy of the PDF will not be released until you exit the `with` statement.  Pulling the text from a PDF file is not an easy task; it is a lot of work.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I have updated it @Tim Roberts